# Stack and evaluate postfix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if anyone can help with this Stack question 
there are 2 example in the main function and the answer should be 1024 and 4096, but I will get 100 and 144
the issue must be in evaluate_postfix definition becuase I know the Stack class is working

```
class Stack:
 def __init__(self):
     self.items = []

 def is_empty(self):
     return self.items == []

 def push(self, item):
     self.items.append(item)

 def pop(self):
     return self.items.pop()

 def peek(self):
     return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

 def size(self):
     return len(self.items)


def evaluate_postfix(text):
     s = Stack()
     for element in text:
          plus = None
          if element.isdigit():
               s.push(int(element))
          elif element == '^':
               plus = s.pop() ** s.pop()
          elif element == "+":
               plus = s.pop() + s.pop()
          elif element == "-":
               plus = s.pop() - s.pop()
          elif element == "*":
               plus = s.pop() * s.pop()
          elif element == "/":
               plus = s.pop() / s.pop()
          if plus is not None:
               s.push(plus)
     return s.pop()



def main():
     print(evaluate_postfix(['2', '10', '^']))
     print(evaluate_postfix(['2', '4', '3', '*', '^']))

main()
```

Comment: Why do you think those are the right answers?  In your first example, you push 2, push 10, then you get the third element which is '^'.  If that is supposed to mean, "raise the most recently added element to the power of the second most recently added element" then the answer is 10^2=100.  If it's supposed to mean, "raise the second most recently added element to the power of the most recently added element" that is 2^10=1024.  The same issue arises with any binary operator that isn't commutative.  Your program isn't wrong, but maybe your interpretation of the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `pop`ing the right elements, but in the wrong order:

```
s.pop() ** s.pop()
```

Once your program reaches that line, for the first example, the stack will look like this: `['2', '10']`. It `pop`s 10, then 2, then raises 10 to the power of 2. Instead, you can use:

```
right = s.pop()
left = s.pop()
left ** right
```

You'll receive the desired answer, `1024`. The same principle applies to the other operators.

Comment: Stacks don't usually support popping from an arbitrary index.  Instead, you'll probably want to pop everything you need and then do the operation:  `left = s.pop(); right = s.pop; plus = left ** right`, etc.

Comment: @mgilson: In the implementation, I don't think it would matter how items are `pop`ed, but you're right about the operation, of course. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I have added a new def and it works very well